# Catch if own UserControl is clicked or not

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mouseevent

I am writing a Wordsearch game to Windows Phone 8.

[screen http://kepfeltoltes.hu/130804/j_t_k_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/130804/j_t_k_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

This is the game window, and those rectangles are own UserControls.
Here is the definition of the rectangles, in XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Kitoltoszin" Stroke="White" Width="100" Height="100" StrokeThickness="3" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray"/>                
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Betu" Width="70" Height="70" 
                   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="42" Foreground="White" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
```

What I want to do is to detect which rectangle was touched and do something with it(for example make its background blue). Is there a simple way to do that? And how can I refresh a page in WP8?

Answer (score 1):

So you need to consume the [`MouseLeftButtonUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event of the `Rectangle`, so you'll add the markup:

```
MouseLeftButtonUp="Kitoltoszin_MouseLeftButtonUp"
```

and then in the code-behind add the handler:

```
private void Kitoltoszin_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // do what you want here
}
```

Comment: this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue); and nothing happens

Comment: @Daniel, use down for that color and up for default color